# Bulk Amazon S3 object redirect with regular expressions

Tags: redirect, amazon-s3, bucket

I want to add ".html" to all the files that do not end with a file extension.

For example: mysite.com/aaa/xxx should be redirected to -> mysite.com/aaa/xxx.html

I want to redirect every * to .html, but only if the file name doesn't end with a file extension.
(I don't want to do it to js files and not to folders ... )
Does the Amazon bucket redirect feature support regular expressions ? 
Can someone post examples with regular expressions ? 
(KeyPrefixEquals ^[^.]$ -> ReplaceKeyPrefixWith $1.html)

Answer (score 1):

S3 does not appear to work on anything but literal string prefix matches and equality comparisons on redirect rules.

There is, however, a fairly straightforward solution, using the Index document setting for the bucket.

If you configure "index.html" as your index document, then mysite.com/aaa/xxx will automatically load mysite.com/aaa/xxx/index.html.

Comment: The problem is that there are many files and we don't want to lose points of SEO since these files are referenced and found by search engines.

We have lots of (old) files without .html and we want to use a permanant (301) redirect.